# How to debug npm itself (not my code) using VS Code?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

`npm` is crashing in `npm`'s code, not mine. I'd like to debug into the `npm` process using the VSCode IDE debugger, so that I can inspect variables up the call stack to try to figure out what's going wrong.

What's the right `launch.json` config to debug `npm` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasted half an hour trying to figure this out, so sharing the answer here to help others.

The trick (at least on my Mac) was to run `npm-cli.js` instead of running the `npm` executable.

Here's the `launch.json` configuration I used to debug `npm outdated -g`.   To debug other npm commands, just change the `args` below.

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Debug NPM Outdated",
  "cwd": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/",
  "args": [
    "npm-cli.js",
    "outdated",
    "-g",
  ],
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "disableOptimisticBPs": true
},
```

I haven't tested to see if his works to debug other code that's run by `npm`, but if this works for debugging webpack plugins then that'd be cool!

BTW the specific `npm` bug that I was trying to catch is fixed in `npm@6.9.1` which should be released soon. See https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/173.